# JSON call fails with JQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I've been searching arround and I can't retrive JSON information from this example. Can anybody help me please?

`var jsonURL = "http://mdc2.cbuc.cat/dmwebservices/index.php?q=dmGetCollectionList/json";`

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON(jsonURL, function(data) {
  alert("Success!");
  alert(data[0].alias); 
})
.success(function() { alert("second success"); })
.error(function() { alert("error"); })
.complete(function() { alert("complete"); });

jqxhr.complete(function(){ alert("second complete"); });
```

I've checked the URL and everywhere it says that is valid and well formated...

Comment: You cannot retrieve JSON from a different domain, only if it is JSONP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that request is not returning proper jsonp, the browser can't interpret it.

If you have access to that server, it would need to be modified to accept a callback function such as `?callback=cbfunc` which would then wrap the json response in a callback function, such as `cbfunc(["foo","bar"]);`

If you do not have access to that server, you can either use a 3rd party solution such as YQL, or you can build a server-side proxy that will make the request for you. For YQL, here's a page that can help:

[http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20json%20WHERE%20url%3D%22http%3A//mdc2.cbuc.cat/dmwebservices/index.php%3Fq%3DdmGetCollectionList/json%22](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=SELECT%20%2a%20FROM%20json%20WHERE%20url=%22http://mdc2.cbuc.cat/dmwebservices/index.php?q=dmGetCollectionList/json%22)

choose the json radio button, then at the bottom of the page you'll find a url. just remove the `callback=cbfunc` part.

This is the url that was generated:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20json%20WHERE%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fmdc2.cbuc.cat%2Fdmwebservices%2Findex.php%3Fq%3DdmGetCollectionList%2Fjson%22&format=json&callback=cbfunc
```

If the request contains any sensitive data, i would suggest against YQL and for using a server-side script to get the data.

Comment: Well... The first answer is the reason why I can't retrive JSON and yours is how can I overpass the problem, right? Thanks you both!

Answer (score 1):

Is the page running that code hosted on `mdc2.cbuc.cat`? Otherwise, you're probably running into the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).